# C#: Alternative to GenericType == null

Tags: c#, generics, null

I need to check a generic object for null, or default(T). But I have a problem... Currently I have done it like this:

```
if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
{
  if(default(T).Equals(thing))
    // Do something
  else
    // Do something else
}
else
{
  if(thing == null)
    // Do something
  else
    // Do something else
}
```

But then I end up repeating myself... which I don't like. The problem is the following:

```
thing == null;
```

Here ReSharper warns about Possible compare of value type with 'null'.

```
thing == default(T);
```

Here I get compiler error: Cannot apply operator '==' to operands of type 'T' and 'T'.

```
thing.Equals(null|default(T));
```

`thing` can obviously be null (that's why I have to check!), so will cause NullReferenceException.

```
null|default(T).Equals(thing);
```

null and default(T) is very often null as well...

Is there a clean way to do this??

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If boxing isn't an issue, you could just use:

```
object.Equals(value, default(T))
```

Comment: I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: I'm surprised at how complex the other answers are for this.

Comment: How hard checking is, depends where you are. Thank you Jeff, will most likely end up with this method =)

Comment: See Jason's answer for a one-liner that doesn't need boxing.

Answer (score 54):

The proper way to do this is:

```
return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, default(T))
```

No boxing. You could even define an extension method like this:

```
public static void bool IsDefault<T>(this T value)
{
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, default(T));
}
```

.. and invoke it like this:

```
return entry.IsDefault();
```

Though, I personally don't care for extension methods on T (e.g. this object IsNull()) since it hampers readability sometimes.

Comment: While I like this response, I may not be appropriate in all cases. One frequent place where this check happens is validating arguments passed to a method. If the intent of this check is to throw an exception when a method receives a null argument, this will not work for the case where someone intentionally passes a 0. In this case, I think reverting to `if (value == null)` works as expected for all cases and is much more readable (and thus clean).

Comment: 0 is the default value of an unboxed integer, but is not the default of a nullable int. Please provide an example method signature that highlights your concern.

Answer (score 8):

When I need to test if the value is NULL I use the method below. I typically use this when calling methods that take any type but not nulls such as the Cache.

```
public static bool IsNull<T>(this T value)
{
    var type = typeof(T);

    return (type.IsClass || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null) 
        && EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, default(T));

}
```

Comment: `Type.IsClass` is false for interfaces. `!Type.IsValueType` is probably what you want. (I believe you still need the nullable check.)

Answer (score 2):

Best thing I can think of at the moment is:

```
return value == null || value.Equals(default(T));
```

Edit:

Apparently, there's a static `object.Equals` method I was not aware of:

```
return object.Equals(value, default(T));
```

This is better.

Comment: but what will then happen if value is a value type?

Comment: (value == null) would return false. (value.Equals(default(T)) would check against the default.

Comment: This only avoids boxing if there is an Equals implementation on the type that is specialized rather than the default that takes an object.  In light of that, I think that object.Equals(value, default(T)) is easier to read.

Comment: @Jeff: I agree. Like I said, object.Equals() is a method I was not aware of.

Comment: @Jeff: The Equals implementation must override object.Equals in order to be called. So this never avoids boxing.

Comment: You can avoid boxing by implementing IEquatable.

Comment: But of course, you need to query for that before resorting to object.Equals.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of boxing will do the job just fine.

```
    static bool IsNullOrDefault<T>(T value)
    {
        return ((object)default(T)) == null ?
            ((object)value) == null :
            default(T).Equals(value);
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this just saying object.Equals(default(T), value)?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid boxing altogether by noting that nullability of a type can be determined statically.

Here is what you can do:

1. Declare a private static read-only variable called `isDefault` of type `Predicate<T>` in your generic class
2. Add a static initializer to your generic class, where you check T's nullability, and set isDefault to either `v==null` or `default(T).Equals(v)` depending on the outcome
3. Use `isDefault(x)` instead of `x==null` in the rest of your code

Here is an example:

```
public class Example<T> {

    private static readonly Predicate<T> isDefault;

    static Example() {
        // Nullability check is a bit ugly, but we do it once per T,
        // so what the heck...
        if (typeof(T).IsValueType &&
           (!typeof(T).IsGenericType
        ||  typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(Nullable<>)
        )) {
            // This is safe because T is not null
            isDefault = val => default(T).Equals(val);
        } else {
            // T is not a value type, so its default is null
            isDefault = val => val == null;
        }
    }

    public bool Check(T value) {
        // Now our null-checking is both good-looking and efficient
        return isDefault(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: What if the method is generic but the class is not?

Answer (score 0):

With Tests:

```
public class DefaultOrNullChecker<T>  {
    public bool Check(object x) {
        return object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || x.Equals(default(T));
    }
}
[TestFixture]
public class Tests {
    [Test]  public void when_T_is_reference_type() { 
        Assert.IsFalse(new DefaultOrNullChecker<Exception>().Check(new Exception()));}
    [Test] public void when_T_is_value_type() { 
        Assert.IsFalse(new DefaultOrNullChecker<int>().Check(123)); }
    [Test] public void when_T_is_null() {
        Assert.IsTrue(new DefaultOrNullChecker<Exception>().Check(null));}
    [Test] public void when_T_is_default_value() { 
        Assert.IsTrue(new DefaultOrNullChecker<int>().Check(0)); }
}
```

Comment: This does not matter at all since the comparison is done on T's constraint vs T's constraint, i.e. object == object. That is the same as object.ReferenceEquals.

Answer (score -1):

What is wrong with this?

```
if (thing == default(T)) { }
```

If it is a value type then the JIT will simply remove the statement altogether.

Comment: It doesn't compile. `Cannot apply operator '==' to operands of type 'T' and 'T'`